# Export from Amazon RDS Postgresql to S3 using aws_s3 extension in gzip format?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I have an Amazon RDS database running PostgreSQL.

I want to export data to an Amazon S3 bucket using the [`aws_s3` extension](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html).

It is working successfully. However, I would like to have it export data in gzip format because exporting it to normal CSV format is taking a longer duration for larger tables.

My table size is >50 GB.

Could someone please suggest me the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a full reply, but I do not currently have enough reputation to *comment* your question.

As I saw in the documentation of AWS for transferring data from RDS for PgSQL to S3 ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html#postgresql-s3-export-examples:%7E:text=%27Wednesday%27)%3B-,Calling%20aws_s3.query_export_to_s3,-The%20following%20shows)) it is possible to pass some `options` arguments to the `aws_s3. query_export_to_s3`, that correspond to PostgreSQL `COPY` arguments.
When going to this `COPY` [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html), it seems you can leverage the [`PROGRAM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html#:%7E:text=the%20path%20name.-,PROGRAM,-A%20command%20to) argument to export as a `.gz` file. An [example](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html#:%7E:text=To%20copy%20into%20a%20compressed%20file%2C%20you%20can%20pipe%20the%20output%20through%20an%20external%20compression%20program%3A) is given below.

I could unfortunately not test it myself, as I don't have the correct rights to install the `aws_s3` extension on my instance, and have to find a workaround, but maybe this might work, or lead you on a path to a similar solution.

Hope this helps ! :)

Comment: Oh yeah, aws is definitely gonna let u run a random shell command against the server hosting redshift...

Comment: I tried it, unfortunately recevied `ERROR: option "program" not recognized`. Regardless since OP's table size is 50GB, it's likely they're limited by disk IOPS and throughput rather than Postgres to S3 bandwidth.

Comment: Was anyone able to get working solution to this question ?